# Why is my user manager not starting up correctly?

Tags: systemd, services, windows-subsystem-for-linux, systemctl, loginctl

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on WSL2 with systemd support enabled. My configuration worked fine until two days ago. I use TMUX and its plugins tmux-resurrect and tmux-continuum, the later one already added a user service that starts my TMUX server when I log in. For some days now I have been writing a custom user service that is supposed to save/restore environment variables for each TMUX pane. The scripts themselves work great, however via the user service at login there are either timing or dependencies issues between my `tmux` (tmux-continuum) and my very own `tmux-environments` service and it does not work. So my idea was to connect as root with another terminal and monitor the service journals, while I log in and out with my user, and also get a sense of the timings and the order of execution.

For that I ran `pkill -KILL -u $USER`, because simply closing all terminals and Visual Studio Code wasn't enough; there were still some processes running under my user. Perhaps its a crux with WSL2, but since I ran that command my user manager doesn't seem to start correctly anymore, although there are no errors visible in the journal.

Below I add the output of several commands at two distinct points in time. The first point in time is just after I start WSL2 and after my user gets logged in. The second point in time is after I manually restarted the user manager.

## After login, before manually restarting the user manager

```bash
sebastian$ systemctl list-unit-files --type=service --user
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory

sebastian$ loginctl show-user sebastian
UID=1000
GID=1000
Name=sebastian
Timestamp=Fri 2022-12-09 16:56:47 CET
TimestampMonotonic=4543003
RuntimePath=/run/user/1000
Service=user@1000.service
Slice=user-1000.slice
Display=c1
State=active
Sessions=c1
IdleHint=no
IdleSinceHint=1670601410831279
IdleSinceHintMonotonic=7494053
Linger=yes

root$ systemctl status user@1000.service
● user@1000.service - User Manager for UID 1000
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/user@.service; static)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/user@.service.d
             └─timeout.conf
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-12-09 16:56:48 CET; 19s ago
       Docs: man:user@.service(5)
   Main PID: 362 (systemd)
     Status: "Startup finished in 65ms."
      Tasks: 2
     Memory: 4.1M
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service
             └─init.scope
               ├─362 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
               └─363 "(sd-pam)"

root$ journalctl --full -u user@1000.service
...
Dec 09 16:56:48 vega systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1000...
Dec 09 16:56:48 vega systemd[362]: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user sebastian(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Dec 09 16:56:48 vega systemd[362]: Queued start job for default target Main User Target.
Dec 09 16:56:48 vega systemd[362]: Created slice User Application Slice.
Dec 09 16:56:48 vega systemd[362]: Reached target Paths.
Dec 09 16:56:48 vega systemd[362]: Reached target Timers.
Dec 09 16:56:48 vega systemd[362]: Starting D-Bus User Message Bus Socket...
Dec 09 16:56:48 vega systemd[362]: Listening on GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Dec 09 16:56:48 vega systemd[362]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers>
Dec 09 16:56:48 vega systemd[362]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Dec 09 16:56:48 vega systemd[362]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Dec 09 16:56:48 vega systemd[362]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Dec 09 16:56:48 vega systemd[362]: Listening on debconf communication socket.
Dec 09 16:56:48 vega systemd[362]: Listening on REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
Dec 09 16:56:48 vega systemd[362]: Listening on D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Dec 09 16:56:48 vega systemd[362]: Reached target Sockets.
Dec 09 16:56:48 vega systemd[362]: Reached target Basic System.
Dec 09 16:56:48 vega systemd[362]: Reached target Main User Target.
Dec 09 16:56:48 vega systemd[362]: Startup finished in 63ms.
Dec 09 16:56:48 vega systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1000.

root$ ls -lah /run/user/1000
total 0
drwx------ 4 sebastian sebastian 120 Dec  9 16:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root      root       80 Dec  9 16:57 ..
drwx------ 3 sebastian sebastian  60 Dec  9 16:56 dbus-1
drwx------ 2 sebastian sebastian  80 Dec  9 16:56 pulse
srwxrwxrwx 1 sebastian sebastian   0 Dec  9 16:56 wayland-0
-rw-rw---- 1 sebastian sebastian   0 Dec  9 16:56 wayland-0.lock
```

Then I run this to manually restart the user manager

```bash
root$ systemctl restart user@1000.service
```

## After manually restarting the user manager

```bash
sebastian$ systemctl list-unit-files --type=service --user
UNIT FILE                                        STATE     VENDOR PRESET
app-snap\x2duserd\x2dautostart@autostart.service generated -
dbus.service                                     static    -
dirmngr.service                                  static    -
gpg-agent.service                                static    -
...

sebastian$ loginctl show-user sebastian
UID=1000
GID=1000
Name=sebastian
Timestamp=Fri 2022-12-09 16:56:47 CET
TimestampMonotonic=4543003
RuntimePath=/run/user/1000
Service=user@1000.service
Slice=user-1000.slice
Display=c1
State=active
Sessions=c1
IdleHint=no
IdleSinceHint=1670601410831279
IdleSinceHintMonotonic=7494053
Linger=yes

root$ systemctl status user@1000.service
● user@1000.service - User Manager for UID 1000
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/user@.service; static)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/system/user@.service.d
             └─timeout.conf
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-12-09 17:06:43 CET; 23s ago
       Docs: man:user@.service(5)
   Main PID: 1315 (systemd)
     Status: "Startup finished in 65ms."
      Tasks: 2
     Memory: 4.1M
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service
             └─init.scope
               ├─1315 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
               └─1316 "(sd-pam)"

root$ journalctl --full -u user@1000.service
...
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[1]: Stopping User Manager for UID 1000...
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[362]: Stopped target Main User Target.
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[362]: Stopped target Basic System.
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[362]: Stopped target Paths.
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[362]: Stopped target Sockets.
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[362]: Stopped target Timers.
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[362]: Closed D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[362]: Closed GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[362]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browsers).
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[362]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[362]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[362]: Closed GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[362]: Closed debconf communication socket.
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[362]: Closed REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[362]: Removed slice User Application Slice.
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[362]: Reached target Shutdown.
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[362]: Finished Exit the Session.
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[362]: Reached target Exit the Session.
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[1]: user@1000.service: Deactivated successfully.
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[1]: Stopped User Manager for UID 1000.
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[1]: Starting User Manager for UID 1000...
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[1315]: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user sebastian(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[1315]: Queued start job for default target Main User Target.
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[1315]: Created slice User Application Slice.
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[1315]: Reached target Paths.
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[1315]: Reached target Timers.
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[1315]: Starting D-Bus User Message Bus Socket...
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[1315]: Listening on GnuPG network certificate management daemon.
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[1315]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (access for web browser>
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[1315]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache (restricted).
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[1315]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[1315]: Listening on GnuPG cryptographic agent and passphrase cache.
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[1315]: Listening on debconf communication socket.
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[1315]: Listening on REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[1315]: Listening on D-Bus User Message Bus Socket.
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[1315]: Reached target Sockets.
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[1315]: Reached target Basic System.
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[1315]: Reached target Main User Target.
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[1315]: Startup finished in 44ms.
Dec 09 17:06:43 vega systemd[1]: Started User Manager for UID 1000.

root$ ls -lah /run/user/1000
total 0
drwx------ 6 sebastian sebastian 220 Dec  9 17:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root      root       80 Dec  9 16:57 ..
srw-rw-rw- 1 sebastian sebastian   0 Dec  9 17:06 bus
drwx------ 3 sebastian sebastian  60 Dec  9 16:56 dbus-1
drwx------ 2 sebastian sebastian 140 Dec  9 17:06 gnupg
srw-rw-rw- 1 sebastian sebastian   0 Dec  9 17:06 pk-debconf-socket
drwx------ 2 sebastian sebastian  80 Dec  9 16:56 pulse
srw-rw-rw- 1 sebastian sebastian   0 Dec  9 17:06 snapd-session-agent.socket
drwxr-xr-x 5 sebastian sebastian 140 Dec  9 17:06 systemd
srwxrwxrwx 1 sebastian sebastian   0 Dec  9 16:56 wayland-0
-rw-rw---- 1 sebastian sebastian   0 Dec  9 16:56 wayland-0.lock
```

As you can see the `loginctl`, `systemctl status` (run as root) and `journalctl` outputs are basically the same but it requires manually restarting the user manager in order to get the `systemd` directory, the `bus` socket and others under `/run/user/1000`. Both necessary to use systemd tools and thus user services, eventually.

However, manually restarting the user manager every time is no solution for me, because login services simply don't start by themselves.

Has anybody an idea what causes this problem and how it can be solved? I am by no means an expert Linux user, so I'd be glad for any advice and tips where I can look further.

Comment: I had a similar problem. How do you log in as `sebastian` user ? Do you log in using `su - sebastian` from `root` or using classic prompt ?

Comment: @thiblcr it's WSL, I only run `ubuntu2204.exe` which was added to Windows Terminal, and that just automatically logs my `sebastian` user in. I don't know whether WSL does it via `su - sebastian` or any other way.

Comment: Ok, so this seems to not be the same issue as mine. Just for information, I discovered that `systemctl --user` does not works when logged with `su - username`. I'm sorry for your issue, I think I cannot help you anymore. I hope you'll find a solution shortly !

Comment: @thiblcr Good question, though -- I had the same question, since WSL doesn't typically activate any "login" process.  That's probably the crux of the problem here.